# Baposter fontscale default value?

Tags: baposter

I want to create a poster with font size 9mm and I use a baposter template. In the .cls there is the scaling factor fontscale and I have seen that increasing the factor the font size gets smaller. What is the default value? Or how may I know the font size of the outcome after the scale up?

Answer (score 3):

Fontscale scales the font as 1/value, check the [documentation](http://stefanmckinnonedwards-new-logolayout.googlecode.com/git-history/logosetup/baposter_guide.pdf) if you need more help

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! You can have a look at [our starter guide](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) to familiarize yourself further with our format. On this site, answers should generally provide a complete solution to the question. If there is an answer in the documentation you linked to, I recommend quoting the relevant section in your answer.